# C language: reading a .txt file

Tags: c, visual-studio, text, fopen, fclose

I'm trying to write a program that reads a text file, using C with Visual Studio.

This is my current code (which doesn't work):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *filePTR;
    char fileRow[100];

    filePTR = fopen_s(&filePTR, "text.txt", "r");

    // Opens the file
    if(filePTR){
        while(!feof(filePTR)) {
            // Reads file row
            fgets(fileRow, 100, filePTR);
            // Displays file row
            printf("%s \n", fileRow);
        }
        printf("\nEnd of file.");
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR! Impossible to read the file.");
    }

    // Closes the file
    fclose(filePTR);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following warning:

> 'filePTR' may be '0': this condition does not meet the function specification 'fclose'.

What am I doing wrong? I haven't been programming in C since a while ...

Comment: If the file doesn't open, then you close it anyway. Why? Also, please check what fopen_s returns.

Comment: `fclose(filePTR);` will be executed even after the `else` block.

Comment: Unrelated, but `while(!feof(filePTR))` -> `while (fgets(fileRow, 100, filePTR) != NULL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems begin long before the `fclose`. This line is incorrect:

```
filePTR = fopen_s(&filePTR, "text.txt", "r");
```

It overwites the file pointer already assigned by passing a pointer as the function argument `&filePTR.`

The function returns an error status, not the file pointer. Please see the [man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019):

> **Return Value** Zero if successful; an error code on failure.

Also, please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

I suggest this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {                        // correct definition
    FILE *filePTR;
    char fileRow[100];

    if(fopen_s(&filePTR, "text.txt", "r") == 0) {
        while(fgets(fileRow, sizeof fileRow, filePTR) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", fileRow);      // the string already contains a newline
        }
        fclose(filePTR);                // only close if it was opened
        printf("\nEnd of file.");
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR! Impossible to read the file.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I moved the `fclose` call up. You can't close a file that you did not open.

Comment: Thats correct. keeping flcose() call open wouldn't harm but fopen should be used as suggested fopen_s(&filePTR, "text.txt", "r") == 0) .